# Usage / handling of non relational datasources in .NET applications

Tags: .net, datasource, relational-database, data-access-layer, data-access

Which .NET (data / middel-tier) technologies / framworks can / should be be used, if the datasource isn't a classical **relational database**, but a **service** or a **remote function call** or whatever ? Are technologies like **WCF RIA services** or **WCF DATA services (OData)** suitable for handling non relational datasources.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [OData](http://odata.org/) for a start. If you can expose your data via OData, you get LINQ support and more out of the box.

You *can* develop a LINQ provider yourself to work with web services etc - for example, there's a "LINQ to Amazon" provider kicking around somewhere. Of course, writing your own provider takes a lot of work.

I can't say I've done any WCF work, but I don't *think* EF would really be suitable for non-relational data.